# Provider notifyListener() stops working after initial run in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm facing a weird problem and I don't exactly know if there is something wrong with the way notifyListener() is called.

Here's how the project is laid out:

In the main.dart file I have multi provider set up.

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => DataHandler(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Settings(),
        ),
      ],
```

In the dataHandler file I have a list called posts and two function one to add fetched posts that is being used like Provider.of(context, listen:false).addPost(data); in home.dart file and a function to favourite the post.

```
class DataHandler extends ChangeNotifier {
  List posts = [];

  void addPosts(List data)
  {
      posts.addAll(data);
      notifyListener();
  }

  void favouritePost(index)
  {
   if (posts[index]['favourite'].isEmpty) {
      posts[index]['favourite'] = [{'favourite_by': Api.userUid}];
    } else {
      posts[index]['favourite'] = [];
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

In the home.dart file which is the first screen after authentication, there is a listView.builder wrapped inside the consumer that returns another widget called postbuilder.dart.

```
 itemCount: provider.posts.length,
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return PostBuilder(
           index: index,
         );
 },
```

What postbuidler has is another stateless widget called postlayout which is basically an empty skelaton like widget where you insert the data to fill the widget:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<DataHandler>(
      builder: (context, provider, child) {
        PostLayout(
            uid: provider.posts[widget.index]['uploaded_by']['uid'],
            username: provider.posts[widget.index]['uploaded_by']
                      ['username'],
            name: provider.posts[widget.index]['uploaded_by']['name'],
            profilePicture: provider.posts[widget.index]['uploaded_by']
                      ['profile_picture'],)
            onFavourite: () {provider.favouritePost(widget.index); //Api call here}
```

When you call onFavourite function it will change the data and also make the API call but will not notify.

Now the problem is when the app is built for production and when installed for the first time every thing would work as expected, but when you close the app and open it again the notifylistener will stop working. However, the interesting thing was there was not a single problem when it was in development.

So I don't know whats wrong, whether it's a provider problem or a flutter problem or just the way project is set up.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem, where u able to find your way around it?